# Solving ODE involving matrices

Tags: calculus, integration, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations

We have a given ODE

> $ K(x)_{_{3 \times 3}}=xC_1K(x)+x^3C_2K'(x)  \tag 1$

where $C_1,C_2$ are constant skew symmetric matrices of dimension $3 \times 3$ with determinant $0$. How do we solve $K(x)$?